# Can i deploy my grails app to app-engine using intellj app-engine plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, intellij-idea

I read so many forums that it's not possible to deploy grails application to google app engine because of grails app-engine plugin hasn't been updated for years.And while I was about to give up i found that its possible to deploy project's using intellij app engine plugin so i simply created a new grails app and deploy it using intellij and there it was.http://mine-1150.appspot.com/ but the problem is that its only able to acess **index.jsp** which is located inside the **WEB-INF directory which contains appengine-web.xml ,web.xml and index.jsp** only and not my controllers.so since i get passed the hard work can any body tell me how i should be able to access my controllers and that's job well done.FYI this is the index.jsp

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>hello there</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app engine has its own way of deploying application to its platform and in ur case it treats ur project as if it was of pure java.so it will create its own directory and jsp files.so u can deploy it but it wouldnt be running in the way u intended it to run